# Mix of regular text and LaTeX in Julia plot title

Tags: plot, latex, julia

Tried everything except what works to get the following title in my plot: `"Volume in m^3 at threshold=30"`. The threshold value should come from a variable called `threshold`.

```
using Plots
using LaTeXStrings

threshold = 30
plot(1:10)
title!("Volume in \$m^3\$ at threshold=$threshold")

# The following works with a hard-coded value for threshold
title!(@L_str("\\textrm{Volume in }m^3\\textrm{ at threshold=30}"))

# The following fails:
s = "\\textrm{Volume in }m^3\\textrm{ for threshold=$threshold}"
title!(@L_str(s))

Error message:
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching 
@L_str(::LineNumberNode, ::Module, ::Symbol)
Closest candidates are:
@L_str(::LineNumberNode, ::Module, ::String) at 
/home/tarik/.julia/packages/LaTeXStrings/YQ4GM/src/LaTeXStrings.jl:68
in expression starting at REPL[25]:1
```

Comment: Did you just need the LaTeX for a superscript or is this just an example of something more complex? You might prefer to use Unicode in simple cases such as `title!("Volume in m³ at threshold=$threshold")`, and a lot of editors for Julia will have shortcuts to input special Unicode characters.

Comment: @htl I did not think about using Unicode. Thanks for pointing that out. I am in the process of learning Julia and have been translating a Python script of mine to compare performance. The frustrating points so far are: Waiting after issuing `using Plots` and waiting further for the first plot to appear. I know there is a way to precompute selected libraries, but why let so many potential users go through that pain? I do not like Atom much and am looking for something better with a good debugger. Any idea? And sorry, I have been venting my frustration.

Comment: The "time to first plot" issue is really annoying for me too; you're not alone in that. I tend to alternate between using Jupyter notebooks and VS Code which has [pretty good support for Julia](https://www.julia-vscode.org/). You might find some more info on the Julia forums from people who know more than me about it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, figured out a solution by avoiding the `L` macro that does not seem to do much other than adding a `$` sign at the beginning and end of strings.

```
using Plots
using LaTeXStrings
threshold = 30
s="\$\\textrm{Volume in }m^3\\textrm{ at threshold=$threshold}\$"
plot(1:30)
title!(s)
```